# File IO Help - Reading in

Tags: java, arrays, io, try-catch

I have made a piece of code that reads in a csv file with this information in it. It contains students names and test marks.

*Christopher Lee,54.0*

*Stanley Wright,90.5*

*Oliver Stewart,75.8*

*Jessica Chang,34.65*

When reading in the file, the file name is inputted by the user as a String.
The contents of the file must be stored in two arrays simultaneously, where student names will be stored as Strings and the test marks will be stored as reals. I have a selection menu with two options, display marks and exit. When "Display Marks" is selected the user inputs the name of the student and the program locates the index number of the name in the array and then the program prints out that same index number but in the array containing the test marks, thus printing out the corresponding test mark.

I have finished most of the code but I need some help troubleshooting it and fixing the IO logic. I'm brand new to file IO. Thanks

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MarksIO
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String fileName;

        fileName = sc.nextLine();
        boolean valid;
        valid = false;
        while (valid)
        {
            int choice = 0;
            System.out.println("Select an Option: ");
            System.out.println("Display Mark = 1.\nExit = 2.");
            if (choice == 1)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter the name of the Student.");
                String name;
                name = sc.nextLine();
                int lines = getNumLines(fileName);
                String[] arrayString = new String[lines];
                double[] arrayReal = new double[lines];
                readFile(arrayString, arrayReal, fileName);
                System.out.println("Test Mark is: " + arrayReal[index]);
            }
            else if (choice == 2)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }

    }

    public static int indexCalc(String name, double[] arrayReal,
            String[] arrayString)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < arrayString.length; index++)
        {
            if (arrayString[index].equals(name))
            {
                return index;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void readFile(String fileName, double[] arrayReal,
            String[] arrayString)
    {
        FileInputStream fileStream = null;
        InputStreamReader reader;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader;
        int lineNum;
        String line;

        try
        {
            fileStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            reader = new InputStreamReader(fileStream);
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);

            for (int i = 0; i <= arrayString.length; i++)
            {
                lineNum = 0;
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                while (line != null)
                {
                    lineNum++;
                    arrayString[i] = processString(line);
                    arrayReal[i] = processReal(line);
                }
            }
            fileStream.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            if (fileStream != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    fileStream.close();
                }
                catch (IOException ex2)
                {

                }
                System.out.println("Error in file processing: "
                        + ex.getMessage());
            }

        }

    }

    public static String processString(String line, String[] arrayString)
    {
        String[] stringArray = line.split(",");
        String string = stringArray[0];
        return string;
    }

    public static double processReal(String line, double[] arrayReal)
    {
        double[] realArray = line.split(",");
        double real;
        real = (double)(realArray[1]);
        return real;

    }

    public static int getNumLines(String fileName)
    {
        FileInputStream fileStream;
        InputStreamReader reader;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader;
        try
        {
            fileStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            reader = new InputStreamReader(fileStream);
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error in file processing: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        int numLines;
        numLines = 0;
        int lineNum = 0;
        String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
        while (line != null)
        {
            lineNum++;
            numLines = numLines + 1;
            line = bufferedReader.readLine();

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile?

Comment: You have some compilation errors like `double[] realArray = line.split(",");` (`String.split(...)` returns a `String[]` not a `double[]`) and `System.out.println(... arrayReal[index]);` (there is no `index` variable in the scope where this statement is).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Scanner class to do this job. like

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScanXan {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Scanner s = null;

        try {
            s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("xanadu.txt")));

            while (s.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(s.next());
            }
        } finally {
            if (s != null) {
                s.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```